# Adding custom Feature attributes to ESRI Shapefile with Python

Tags: esri, geodjango, shapefile, osgeo, ogr

I am seeking a way to take an existing ESRI Shapefile that has a Feature set of 200 countries. Each country Feature has an attribute of "NAME." My objective is to create a Python script that adds an arbitrary (for now) additional attribute, say, "POPULATION".

Of course I have the OSGeo and GeoDjango modules installed. I'm as far as:

```
from osgeo import ogr

infile = ogr.Open('sample.shp', 1) #'sample.shp' is a pre-existing ESRI shapefile described above
inlyr = infile.GetLayerByIndex(0)
```

Am I missing an OGR function that will allow me to insert Feature attribute fields into an existing Shapefile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add a field you have to create an OGRFieldDefn and then call inlyr.CreateField

```
fieldDefn = ogr.FieldDefn('POPULATION', ogr.OFTReal) 
fieldDefn.SetWidth(14) 
fieldDefn.SetPrecision(6)
inlyr.CreateField(fieldDefn)
```

Comment: Then subsequent to this do I need to call a Destroy() to write the data?

Comment: To close the file it is recommended to use `infile = None`

Comment: What if you want the field you are creating to be of the `string` type?

Comment: Found the answer myself: http://www.gdal.org/ogr__core_8h.html#a787194bea637faf12d61643124a7c9fc